# How do I get an if elif else statement to restart

Tags: python, jython

I am a newbie, and am having trouble getting the following code to process.

choice

if: (statement is false)

```
  moves to elif statement
```

elif: (statement is false)

```
  moves to else statement
```

else: (I would like for the loop to go back up to choice to retry the if and 
       elif statements

I tried some different indentations and such, but I'm sure I'm missing something else to retrigger the loop.

Answer (score 3):

`if` is not a loop, it is a conditional. Therefore, there is no loop for you to restart.

`while` is a loop. (There are others that do slightly different things.) It can't branch like `if`, it just loops.

If you need to make a decision in a loop, put `if` inside of `while`. No single statement is designed to do everything.

```
while True:    # repeats forever
    feedback = get_user_feedback()
    if feedback_is_this_way(feedback):
        go_this_way()
    elif feedback_is_that_way(feedback):
        go_that_way()
    elif feedback_says_user_is_sick_and_tired(feedback):
        apologise_to_user()
        break    # exits the loop
    else:
        tell_the_user_not_to_mess_around()
```

Comment: plus 1 for `tell_the_user_not_to_mess_around` :D

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting the conditional block in a function and then call the function again for the else condition:

```
def conditionCheck():
    if (...):
        #do stuff
    elif (...):
        #do stuff
    else:
        conditionCheck()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for a [`while`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp) loop. For this example, the code will continue at the top until the user enters `exit`.

```
while True:
    item = input('Enter text: ')
    if item == 'banana':
        print('You entered: {}'.format(item))
    elif item == 'apple':
        print('You entered: {}'.format(item))
    elif item == 'cherry':
        print('You entered: {}'.format(item))
    elif item == 'exit':
        break
    else:
        print('You did not enter a fruit, try again!')
```

Some example output

```
Enter text: banana
You entered: banana
Enter text: apple
You entered: apple
Enter text: cherry
You entered: cherry
Enter text: exit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    if condition_one:
       pass
    elif condition_two:
       pass
    else:
        continue
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'While True' and 'Break' within the 'if' and 'elif' statements are what you want to concern yourself with
Here is a full working example:

```
print('Hello welcome to the Coffee House!')

name=input('\nWhat is your name?\n')

print('\nHello ' +(name) +'!\n')

menu= 'Americano, Cappucino, Latte, Espresso'

print('What would you like today? Here is our menu... \n\n' +menu)

Americanoprice = '£1.00'
Cappuchinoprice = '£1.50'
Latteprice = '£1.50'
Espressoprice = '£1.00' 

while True:
  order =input()

if (order=='Americano'):
  print('\nSounds good ' +name+ '.' + ' That will be '+Americanoprice + ' please')


elif (order=='Cappuchino'):
  print('\nSounds good ' +name+ '.' + ' That will be ' +Cappuchinoprice + ' please')


elif (order == 'Latte'):
  print('\nSounds good ' +name+ '.' + ' That will be ' +Latteprice + ' please.')


elif(order == 'Espresso'):
  print('\nSounds good ' +name+ '.' + ' That will be' +Espressoprice +' please.')
  
  break 

else:
  print('\nSorry but we do not have that. Would you like anything else?')
```

Test out the code yourself to see how everything works.